# How to test my dll file written in fortran?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, fortran, intel

I have written a Fortran code for being compiled as a '*.DLL'  file.

The program which reads that file is a Finite Elements Method software named Plaxis, I already achieved to generate the '*.DLL' file in Visual Studio and Plaxis recognizes my model but the model does not work fine.

I would like to evaluate all the variables involved in my code and the procedure that Plaxis is using to read them, but when I use commands like "write(*,*) 'variable'" Plaxis does not show me what I asked in the source code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include the section of your code that produces the problem so that we can help you.

Comment: Here is a set of guidelines by Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/535304

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to open a file and write to that for debug logging, because presumably Plaxis doesn't run with standard output connected to anything useful.  Or maybe it would if you just ran Plaxis from a command line window?

It's not going to create a dialog box for you.

But anyway, another option would might be attach to Plaxis with a debugger, and set a breakpoint in a function in your DLL.  Then you can single-step your code as called by Plaxis.

Or you can write your own test callers and write unit tests for your functions, making them easy to debug.  This could work well if your function just gets an array + size as args.

If instead it passes some wrapped object that you need to call special functions to deal with, then maybe make another version of your function that *does* just take an array so you can call it from a simple test caller.